# How can I set the options in blender in the bottom?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to do this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDZjgSKbx-Y&feature=youtu.be

At the second 0:18 he changed so the object have holes around and also he got a menu on the bottom but I don't have it.

[image: The tutorial image]

And this is my blender. Not sure how to make this holes and not sure how to get the menu he got on the bottom. Now it's setting to Timeline in my blender but I'm not sure to what to change it to :

[image: My blender]

Comment: The "holes" are dots marking the center of faces, meaning he is in face select mode (Shortcut key - 3 ). You can also get there by pressing the farthest right of the three quare buttons in the top left between where it says "edit mode", and "view". Squares (from left to right) are Vertex select, Edge Select, and Face select.

Comment: In blender 2.8 I think it also means that its in xray transparency mode, because in solid mode the dots don't appear

Comment: @Nascent Space. I think you may be correct. It's weird, in my mind, they're always there when I picture face select mode - I had to go check to see that they're not. I guess I spend more time in X-ray than I thought.